# Calculating the area of 2D shapes

Tags: c++

I'm creating a class called `Geometry` to calculate the area of a circle, rectangle, or triangle, based on the number of parameters provided to the constructor. The constructors accept 1, 2, and 3 parameters respectively.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
class Geometry
{
    private:
        int a,b,c,d,e,r;
        float pi=3.14;
    public:
        void input()
        {
            cout<<"Enter the value of a,b,c,d,r";
            cin>>a;
            cin>>b;
            cin>>c;
            cin>>d;
            cin>>e;
            cin>>r;
        }
       void calculate();
       void display();
        Geometry (int);
        Geometry (int,int);
        Geometry (int,int,int);
    };
    Geometry :: Geometry(int p)
    {
        p=r;
        float pi=3.14;

    }
    Geometry :: Geometry (int x,int y)
    {
        x=a,y=b;
    }
    Geometry :: Geometry (int f,int g,int h)
    {
        f=c,g=d,h=e;
    }
    void calculate()
    {
        int a,b,c,d,e,r;
        float s;
        s=(c+d+e)/2;
        float areat,areac,arear;
        areat=sqrt(s*(s-c)*(s-d)*(s-e));
        arear=(a*b);
        areac=(3.14*r*r);
}
    void display()
    {
     float areac,areat,arear;
     cout<<"area of circle is:"<<areac;
     cout<<"area of rectangle is:"<<arear;
     cout<<"area of triangle is:"<<areat;
    }
    int main()
    {
        Geometry z;
        z.calculate();
        z.display();
        getch();
    }
```

The errors I'm receiving are:

> no matching function for call Geometry::Geometry() in line 59

and

> candidates expected 2 arguments o provided in line 33

What do these mean and how can I resolve these errors?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, look at the constructors you defined and then look at how you are calling your class.  You didn't specify a constructor that takes 0 arguments.

A few things that will turn into errors once you finish the constructor issue:

The methods are going to need to know which class they belong to.

```
void Geometry::calculate(){...} 
void Geometry::display(){...}
```

Also (just being picky) you should probably make all the variables that don't change constant, ie

```
float pi = 3.14
```

should be const.

Also, I don't think you need  `#include <stdio.h>` as it's a C++ program and `stdio.h` is C.

**EDIT:**

I think `getch()` should be defined in conio.h. So throw that include in there (or use something like sleep()) and have fun programming.

The error message is telling you that the constructors that you programmed take 2 or 3 arguments, but you didn't provide any in your main function when you initialized your Geometry class.

```
Geometry z; // Uses constructor Geometry(); which doesn't exist
Geometry z(5); // Uses constructor Geometry(int p);
Geometry z(5, 6); // Uses constructor Geometry(int x, int y);
Geometry z(5, 6, 7); // Uses constructor Geometry(int f, int g, int h);
```